# Permutations - n people and n seats

Tags: permutations

Actually, it seams pretty simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Imagine we have a room containing $n$ seats in a row and $n$ people waiting in front of the room. The first person that enters the room can decide where he wants to sit. The remaining $(n-1)$ people must take a seat next to an already sitting person. What is the number of ways to sit all the people in the room?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a person enters, he/she can decide to sit at a seat to the left of everyone who is already sitting, or to the right of everyone sitting. Suppose the first person sits on the $k^{th}$ seat from the left, exactly $k-1$ people can go and sit to the left side seat. Thus, the number of seating arrangements with the first person sitting on the $k^{th}$ seat from the left is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. Adding all these individual solutions for $k=1,2,...,n$ gives, the total number of seating arrangements as $\binom{n-1}{0} + \binom{n-1}{1} + ... + \binom{n-1}{n-1} = 2^{n-1}$

Comment: It's not clear to me how $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ maintains the correct, ordering, could you please expand on this?

Comment: @David: Once the first person sits down (say, in the $k$th seat), there are $n-1$ open seats, of which $k-1$ are on the right. Each of the remaining $n-1$ people, as they come up, have only two choices: They can sit to the left of the leftmost person (if that seat is available), or to the right of the rightmost person (if *that* seat is available). Therefore, the final arrangement depends only on the sequence of L(eft) and R(ight) they choose; we can denote this sequence by writing $n-1$ symbols in a row, of which $k-1$ are L and $n-k$ are R. There are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ such sequences.

Comment: This then needs to be summed up over all possible values of seat indices $k$ from $1$ to $n$ that the first person could have chosen, yielding $2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

The constraint "take a seat next to an already sitting person" implies that there are no gaps between occupied seats.

Let us assume that there are $K$ ways to place $n$ people. If we increase the number of people to $n+1$, we can add the seat from the right or from the left and thus increase the number of ways from $K$ to $2K$. For $n=1$ we start with $K=1$. Therefore, for $n$ we get $K=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I like the recursive idea!

Comment: When you say $K$ ways to place $n$ people. You mean $K$ ways to place $n$ people in exactly $n$ seats right?

Comment: Yes. That is being asked for in the question.